# Backport Tensorflow models

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Is it possible to load (or backport) a SavedModel/Keras model which has been created with tensorflow 2.x to an environment using tensorflow 1.x?

I created both model types using [Teachable Machine](https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/) and tried to load them with tensorflow 1.14 on an old RaspPi (Its the most recent version I could install on this hardware without errors). However, this results in errors:

Using Keras Model:

```
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, save_model, load_model
    model = load_model('keras_model.h5')

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py in load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
        208     if model_config is None:
        209       raise ValueError('No model found in config file.')
    --> 210     model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
        211     model = model_config_lib.model_from_config(model_config,
        212                                                custom_objects=custom_objects)
    
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Using SavedModel:

```
    model = tf.saved_model.load('model_savedmodel')
    
    TypeError: load() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'tags' and 'export_dir'
```

Comment: TensorFlow 2.x saved_models work in TensorFlow 1.x if all the ops are supported. For more details check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#saved_models_compatibility). Thanks!

Comment: @TFer Then Teachable Machine seems to use one of these unsupported ops and I don't know how to find out which ones and how to remove/convert them.
Still good to know, thank you!